# matplotlib 1.4.2 with Seaborn: line markers not functioning

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, seaborn

Note: this is fixed in 1.4.3 or later

---

I use the Seaborn plotting package and I just upgraded to the newest version of Matplotlib. Now, plots with dot symbols no longer render. Code that was functional before now creates blank plots, but only when Seaborn is imported. Here's some sample code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib
import numpy as np

print matplotlib.__version__
```

Matplotlib version:

```
1.4.2
```

Create a plot without seaborn:

```
x = np.linspace(0,2,101)
y = np.sin(2*np.pi*x)
plt.plot(x,y,'.')
```

[image: sin function with dots at each data point]

Import seaborn, print the version:

```
import seaborn as sns
print sns.__version__
```

Seaborn version:

```
0.4.0
```

Create a line plot with seaborn imported:

```
plt.plot(x,y,'-')
```

[image: sin function with a solid line connecting each data point]

Creating a dot plot with seaborn imported gives a blank set of axes:

```
plt.plot(x,y,'.')
```

[image: an empty set of axes]

Everything above was done in the IPython notebook, but I just tried the following in Spyder with the same result:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib
import numpy as np

print matplotlib.__version__

x = np.linspace(0,2,101)
y = np.sin(2*np.pi*x)
plt.figure()
plt.plot(x,y,'.')

import seaborn as sns
print sns.__version__
plt.figure()
plt.plot(x,y,'-')

plt.figure()
plt.plot(x,y,'.')

plt.show()
```

What's going on?

Comment: I'm seeing a similar issue with Matplotlib 2.0.0 and seaborn 0.6.0, although in my case, plotstyle `.` works fine but plotstyle `+` does not.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It would appear that this is due to a bug in Matplotlib.

https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/3711

https://github.com/mwaskom/seaborn/issues/344

You might just have to downgrade for the time being.

PS: What's up Doug.

Comment: I added a note on the seaborn issue thread about a workaround in seaborn that should avoid this issue for the time being.

Comment: The posted workaround on the seaborn issue thread solves the problem. Just to save others a click over there, I put the following after my seaborn import call: sns.set_context(rc={'lines.markeredgewidth': 0.1}). Thanks Derric and mwaskom!

Comment: For those who end up here but don't click through to the issue, seaborn 0.5.1 has been released with a workaround for this bug.

Comment: I just installed seaborn 0.5.1 and the issue persists. Using this code to plot: `import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib
import numpy as np
import seaborn as sns
plt.plot(np.arange(10),marker='+')
plt.show()` Version 1.4.2. for matplotlib and 0.5.1. for seaborn. If I have seaborn imported the markers don't show, but they do show without seaborn.

Answer (score 1):

A workaround (mentioned in the GitHub links in the other answer) is to explicitly set `markeredgewidth` (or `mew`) in the call to `plot`:

```
plt.plot(x,y,'.', mew=1)
```