# Unexpected behaviour in matplotlib when markevery='float' is used in a log-log scaling plot

Tags: matplotlib, jupyter-notebook

Matplotlib version alongside Ubuntu 14.04 LTS, Python 2.7 and Jupyter 4.1.1:

```
>>> import matplotlib
>>> matplotlib.__version__
'2.0.2+4277.g3ecd965'
```

Create a log-log plot:

```
t = np.arange(0.0, 600.0, 2.0)
plt.loglog(t, 20 * np.exp(-t / 10.0), marker='o', markevery=0.1, linestyle='None')
```

[image]

[Expected that](https://matplotlib.org/api/lines_api.html#matplotlib.lines.Line2D.set_markevery):

> markers will be spaced at approximately equal distances along the line

Yet, no marker was observed. When the starting point of the array was slightly shifted to the side of positive numbers, the markers appeared. Compare:

```
t = np.arange(0.01, 600.0, 2.0)
plt.loglog(t, 20 * np.exp(-t / 10.0), marker='o', markevery=0.1, linestyle='None')
```

[image]

Note that the markers disappeared when a negative starting value was used. **Moreover**, other *markerevery* options worked out nicely.

Any idea is highly appreciated.

PS: Here is a similar question: [matplotlib 1.4.2 with Seaborn: line markers not functioning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26618339/matplotlib-1-4-2-with-seaborn-line-markers-not-functioning)
.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The logarithm of 0 is minus infinity. Minus infinity plus some value (here plus 0.1) is still minus infinity. Therefore all points that *are not* minus infinity are not shown. But of course the points that *are* at minus infinity are also not shown because minus infinity is no numerical value. In total, no point is shown at all, as expected.

If you chose the first point to give some numerical value, markevery is of course working fine.