# Python: Changing Marker Type in Seaborn

Tags: python, matplotlib, graph, seaborn

In regular matplotlib you can specify various marker styles for plots. However, if I import `seaborn`, '+' and 'x' styles stop working and cause the plots not to show - others marker types e.g. 'o', 'v', and '*' work.

Simple example:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

x_cross = [768]
y_cross = [1.028e8]
plt.plot(x_cross, y_cross, 'ok')

plt.gca().set_xlim([10, 1e4])
plt.gca().set_ylim([1, 1e18])
plt.xscale('log')
plt.yscale('log')

plt.show()
```

Produces this: [Simple Seaborn Plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J9JAF.png)

Changing 'ok' on line 6 to '+k' however, no longer shows the plotted point. If I don't import `seaborn` it works as it should: [Regular Plot With Cross Marker](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VnGj6.png)

Could someone please enlighten me as to how I change the marker style to a cross type when `seaborn` being used?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The reason for this behaviour is that seaborn sets the marker edge width to zero. (see [source](https://github.com/mwaskom/seaborn/blob/master/seaborn/rcmod.py#L361)).

As is pointed out in the [seaborn known issues](http://seaborn.pydata.org/installing.html?highlight=markeredgewidth#known-issues)

> An unfortunate consequence of how the matplotlib marker styles work is that line-art markers (e.g. `"+"`) or markers with `facecolor` set to `"none"` will be invisible when the default seaborn style is in effect. This can be changed by using a different `markeredgewidth` (aliased to `mew`) either in the function call or globally in the rcParams.

[This issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26618339/matplotlib-1-4-2-with-seaborn-line-markers-not-functioning) is telling us about it as well as [this one](https://github.com/mwaskom/seaborn/issues/344).

In this case, the solution is to set the markeredgewidth to something larger than zero,

- using rcParams (after importing seaborn):

  ```
  plt.rcParams["lines.markeredgewidth"] = 1
  ```
- using the `markeredgewidth` or `mew` keyword argument

  ```
  plt.plot(..., mew=1)
  ```

However, as @mwaskom points out in the comments, there is actually more to it. In [this issue](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/4679) it is argued that markers should be divided into two classes, bulk style markers and line art markers. This has been partially accomplished in matplotlib version 2.0 where you can obtain a "plus" as marker, using `marker="P"` and this marker will be visible even with `markeredgewidth=0`.

```
plt.plot(x_cross, y_cross, 'kP')
```

[image]

Comment: Ah; I guess I should always check 'known issues' first in future. Thanks for expanding on the previous answer.

Comment: The two issues you link to are actually a similar but separate issue that was a bug in matplotlib 1.4.2. The most relevant issue is in the matplotlib github here: https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/4679. This was handled in matplotlib 2. by adding "filled" versions of lineart markers, e.g. `"P"` will draw a plus regardless of the linewidth setting.

Answer (score 2):

It is very like to be a bug. However you can set marker edge line width by `mew` keyword to get what you want:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

x_cross = [768]
y_cross = [1.028e8]

# set marker edge line width to 0.5
plt.plot(x_cross, y_cross, '+k', mew=.5)

plt.gca().set_xlim([10, 1e4])
plt.gca().set_ylim([1, 1e18])
plt.xscale('log')
plt.yscale('log')

plt.show()
```

[image]